# Adding metadata tags (like title, artist, album) to audio file not working (Android MediaStore)

Tags: android, mediastore, android-file

I want to create an audio file and set the title, artist and album tags of the song using Android MediaStore. Creating the file works but unfortunately the tags don't seem to be set. What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
    private long createFile(Context context, String fileName, InputStream fileContent) throws IOException {
        Uri audioCollection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "some title");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "some artist");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, "some album");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(audioCollection, contentValues);

        FileOutputStream out = (FileOutputStream) contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri);
        FileChannel outChannel = out.getChannel();

        ReadableByteChannel inChannel = Channels.newChannel(fileContent);

        outChannel.transferFrom(inChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        out.close();

        long id = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        return id;
    }
```

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "STARTED");
            try {
                String songUrl = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3";
                InputStream in = new URL(songUrl).openStream();

                long id = createFile(getApplicationContext(), "songname", in);
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CREATED FILE WITH ID " + id);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? I need the ContentResolver Object to insert or update the ContentValues.
I'm trying to set the song title, artist and album (ID3 Tags) so that my media player app shows it correctly (currently it only shows the filename).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I updated my post.

Comment: Android obtains the values from the appropriate ID3 tags which are part of a track. I use libraries such as jaudiotagger and jid3 to edit and update mp3 tags but these libraries are old and do no longer work (because of their file io) very well with android 10 +. I have not found anything suitable yet

Comment: Since it doesn't seem to be possible to set metadata using the MediaStore I ended up coding a tag editor myself (ID3v1 only). Take a look at the answer I posted, it should work on every android version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand right now it's not possible to set ID3 tags using the MediaStore, it only saves the tags locally on the device, so the metadata is lost when moving the file to another device.

So in the end I created my own tag editor (for ID3v1). Sourcecode if anyone is interested: https://github.com/nh7dev/ID3v1TagEditorJava

ID3v2 is more complex: https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0

Comment: @nh, I am very interested but trouble is with android10+ where explicit permissions are required. Jid3 and jauiotagger do not incorporate the SAF framework, does yours?

Comment: Sorry I don't know I have never used the SAF framework. If you can get a File or FileChannel instance with read an write permissions it should work

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - And why you dont youse mp3tag f.e ?

I am looking for a possibility to find my music by custom tags on android.
Would be nice with foobar mobile.

On hydrogenaudio I recieved the answer, that android at all will not index them.
Perhaps you have an idea that helps ;-)

https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=122435.new#new